# Can you use Google Play Games API in apps other than games?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I want to add achievements to my app. I started doing such my way, but after the last release, with the new Games API, I've seen it looks clearly better than coding all by myself. **What I don't know if there are clauses that avoid using the Game API for regular apps rather than games.**

PS: I've checked twice the [Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) website, but nothing appears there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with that!

This concept is called gamification:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification